# Однокоренные ли слова?

Tags: однокоренные-слова

Может, мой вопрос глупый, но подумалось: а "хлеб" и "хлебать" — однокоренные слова или нет? И, если да, то какая между ними связь? Хлебают ведь что-то жидкое.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Слово **ХЛЕБ** считается заимствованием из герм. языков. Ср. гот. hieifs; др.-в.-нем. hlieb; др.-исл. hieifr <хлеб>. Соврем. форма **хлеб** развилась из др.-рус. хлѣбъ - тожд. вследствие перехода ѣ> е и утраты слаб. редуцир. ъ (в укр. хліб - тожд. ѣ> i). Др.-рус. (и ст.-сл.) хлѣбъ развилось из праслав. *хlеibъ, в нем ei > ѣ.

Допускается также, что слав. *xleibъ и герм. hlieb заимствованы из яз. балтов. Ср. лит. klepos <хлеб>, топоним Клайпеда букв. значит <хлебоеда>; лтш. klaips <буханка, каравай>.

Что касается слова **ХЛЕБАТЬ**, то, по-мнению М.Фасмера, оно скорее всего является звукоподражательным, как *хлипать*. Ср.: *хлюпать, хляби небесные* и пр. Вы правильно отметили в слове **хлебать** сему 'есть что-то жидкое'.

Как видите, слова не являются однокоренными, поскольку появились в языке разными путями.

Answer (score 0):

Просто для справки приведу соображения о родственности слов, изложенные, например, у Льва Успенского ("Слово о Словах" и, какжется, в других его книгах).
Он считает слова родсвенными по причине того что значально "хлеб" и означало похлебку из растертых зерен (теперь бы сказали - заправленную мукой). Другого способа употребления зереновых тогда якобы еще не знали.
Само по себе факт такой похлебки сомнения не вызывает, но вот с хронологией тут, похоже, что-то не так.
Добавлю, что Успенский был великолепным популяризатором, но достоверность многих приводимых им из книги в книну версий - под большим вопросом.

Comment: Спасибо. Я тоже слышала об этой версии. Мне она казалась даже заслуживающей внимания. Но словари, хоть и не опровергают ее, но и не поддерживают.